# Altura de 100VH porem pagina contem barra de rolagem

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tenho essa pagina, que coloquei a altura da pagina em `100VH`, para ocupar toda tela, porem ela esta gerando esses espaços branco em baixo e lado, e isto esta fazendo aparecer barras de rolagem, não sei porque.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura HTML e CSS ( SASS ):

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
}
.background {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 47, 75, .6), rgba(177, 28, 23, .5)), url("../imgs/backpizza.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;

  .col-auto {
    padding: 0.3rem;
  }
  img {
    width: 6rem;

  }
  h4{
    color: snow;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;

  }
}

/*.row .verticalalign{
  height: 100vh;
}*/
.headline h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  @include media-breakpoint-down(lg){
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;

  }
}

.btnbottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  //background-color: $red !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: .3rem;
  @include border-bottom-radius(0);
  @include media-breakpoint-down(lg){
    display: none;

  }

}

.card {
  //@include box-shadow(0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12));
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  //transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);

  &:hover {
    //box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);

  }
  .card-img-top {
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    @include border-top-radius($border-radius);
  }
  .card-body {
    padding: .3rem;
    .rowphone, .rowaaddresses {
      color: $gray-800;
    }
    .card-title {
      margin-bottom: .3rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: $red;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    hr {
      margin-top: .1rem;
      margin-bottom: .1rem;
      border: 0;
      border-top: 1.2px solid $gray-600;
    }
  }
  .card-footer .btn {
    @include border-top-radius(0);
    padding: .275rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper background text-center">
    <header>
        <nav class="row justify-content-center logo">
<!--     era div no lugar de nav-->
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
        <h4>Pizza</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="../assets/imgs/pizzalogo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
        <h4>Vix</h4>
    </div>
</nav>    </header>
    <div class="wrapper-content">
        <!--<section>
            <div class="cover">
                <header>
                    <div class="container">

                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        </section>-->
        <section class="block-content row align-items-center">
            <div class="container">
                <header>
                    <div class="mx-auto headline">
    <h1>As Melhores</h1>
    <h1>Pizzarias</h1>
    <h1>da Grande Vitória</h1>
</div>                </header>
                <div class="card-deck px-5">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-0">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-0">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-0">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>            </div>
        </section>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btnbottom text-uppercase">Conheça mais</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="/assets/_jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/_fontawesome/fa-solid.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/_fontawesome/fontawesome.min.js">
<script src="/assets/js/scrollsmooth.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Igor tem dois jeitos de resolver isso. O primeiro que é o que eu acho mais adequado seria trocando as classes **ROW** da `nav` e da `section` por `d-flex`. Então remove a classe `row` e substitui por `d-flex` Pois a classe Row tem margens que está atrapalhando seu layout e gerando esses espaços e a barra de rolagem.

A outra maneira seria deixa a classe `row`, porém tirando os margins na mão... tipo `nav.row, section.row {margin-left:0; margin-right:0}`

Vou colocar a resposta que julgo mais correta que seria com o `.d-flex` no lugar da `.row` *(no entanto ainda tem coisa pra mexer no CSS, só fiz a parte para resolver esse problema do Scroll indesejado e do espaço em branco ok)* ***Adaptei o SASS para CSS para funcionar aqui, mas depois vc arruma isso como quiser ok***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name=
 content=
>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    .wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
}
.background {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 47, 75, .6), rgba(177, 28, 23, .5)), url("https://baconmockup.com/500/380") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .col-auto {
    padding: 0.3rem;
  }
  img {
    width: 6rem;

  }
  h4{
    color: snow;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;

  }
}

/*.row .verticalalign{
  height: 100vh;
}*/
.headline h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;

}

.btnbottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  //background-color: $red !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: .3rem;


}

.card {

  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);

  }
  .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  }
  .card-img-top {
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;

  }
  .card-body {
    padding: .3rem;

}
.card-title {
      margin-bottom: .3rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: $red;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .card-title hr {
      margin-top: .1rem;
      margin-bottom: .1rem;
      border: 0;
      border-top: 1.2px solid $gray-600;
    }
.rowphone, .rowaaddresses {
      color: $gray-800;
    }
.card-footer .btn {
   
   padding: .275rem;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
        <body>
                <div class="wrapper background text-center">
                    <header>
                        <nav class="d-flex justify-content-center logo">
                <!--     era div no lugar de nav-->
                    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
                        <h4>Pizza</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <img src="http://placeskull.com/50/50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
                        <h4>Vix</h4>
                    </div>
                </nav>    </header>
                    <div class="wrapper-content">
                        <!--<section>
                            <div class="cover">
                                <header>
                                    <div class="container">
                
                                    </div>
                                </header>
                            </div>
                        </section>-->
                        <section class="block-content d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="container">
                                <header>
                                    <div class="mx-auto headline">
                    <h1>As Melhores</h1>
                    <h1>Pizzarias</h1>
                    <h1>da Grande Vitória</h1>
                </div>                </header>
                                <div class="card-deck px-5">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
                            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
                            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                                <div class="position-absolute">
                                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                                <div class="position-absolute">
                                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer p-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
                            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
                            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                                <div class="position-absolute">
                                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                                <div class="position-absolute">
                                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer p-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
                            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
                            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                                <div class="position-absolute">
                                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                                <div class="position-absolute">
                                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer p-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>            </div>
                        </section>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btnbottom text-uppercase">Conheça mais</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

    
   
</body>
</html>
```

**Execute em "Página toda" para visualizar melhor**.

Comment: era isso mesmo, as margens negativas de -15 no row, tambem funciona usar o no-glutters

Comment: @IgorOliveira *“e ja conferir, problemas com margins e padding não é – Igor Oliveira 13 horas atrás”* :)

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece pois você o navegador adiciona alguns valores padrão em seu site, como por exemplo o `padding` e o `margin`.

Para corrigir, basta resetar esses valores, por exemplo:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Exemplo completo:**

```css
* { padding:0;margin:0; }
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
}
.background {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 47, 75, .6), rgba(177, 28, 23, .5)), url("../imgs/backpizza.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;

  .col-auto {
    padding: 0.3rem;
  }
  img {
    width: 6rem;

  }
  h4{
    color: snow;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;

  }
}

/*.row .verticalalign{
  height: 100vh;
}*/
.headline h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  @include media-breakpoint-down(lg){
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;

  }
}

.btnbottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  //background-color: $red !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: .3rem;
  @include border-bottom-radius(0);
  @include media-breakpoint-down(lg){
    display: none;

  }

}

.card {
  //@include box-shadow(0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12));
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  //transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);

  &:hover {
    //box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);

  }
  .card-img-top {
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    @include border-top-radius($border-radius);
  }
  .card-body {
    padding: .3rem;
    .rowphone, .rowaaddresses {
      color: $gray-800;
    }
    .card-title {
      margin-bottom: .3rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: $red;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    hr {
      margin-top: .1rem;
      margin-bottom: .1rem;
      border: 0;
      border-top: 1.2px solid $gray-600;
    }
  }
  .card-footer .btn {
    @include border-top-radius(0);
    padding: .275rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper background text-center">
    <header>
        <nav class="row justify-content-center logo">
<!--     era div no lugar de nav-->
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
        <h4>Pizza</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="../assets/imgs/pizzalogo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
        <h4>Vix</h4>
    </div>
</nav>    </header>
    <div class="wrapper-content">
        <!--<section>
            <div class="cover">
                <header>
                    <div class="container">

                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        </section>-->
        <section class="block-content row align-items-center">
            <div class="container">
                <header>
                    <div class="mx-auto headline">
    <h1>As Melhores</h1>
    <h1>Pizzarias</h1>
    <h1>da Grande Vitória</h1>
</div>                </header>
                <div class="card-deck px-5">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-0">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-0">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top border-bottom border-primary" src="../assets/imgs/braz-pizzaria.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
            <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
            <div class="rowphone px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold">(27) 3974-5134</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowaaddresses px-3 my-2">
                <div class="position-absolute">
                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h6 class="card-text text-center font-weight-bold ">Av. Rio Branco, 375</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-0">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Saiba Mais</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>            </div>
        </section>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btnbottom text-uppercase">Conheça mais</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="/assets/_jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/_fontawesome/fa-solid.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/_fontawesome/fontawesome.min.js">
<script src="/assets/js/scrollsmooth.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Algumas pessoas utilizam “técnicas” de *reset css*. Isso ajuda a pessoa a ter mais controle da página.

Comment: não é isso, pois eu ja utilizo o reboot do bootstrap

Comment: Se tiver o link do site ajuda bastante, no exemplo que postei resolveu com o código acima. De qualquer forma, caso não tenha tentando, tente adicionar o código acima após chamar o arquivo do *Bootstrap*.

Comment: @IgorOliveira Verifique também as margens no *Inspecionar Elementos*

Comment: To rodando em local host, não tenho link, e ja conferir, problemas com margins e padding não é